# How to make TButton as transparent in Firemonkey

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I am using Delphi XE6. I have home screen of Android App. The Home screen contains Tbutton(s) with TImage(s) on top. I need to make TButton transparent and get rid of border of TImage.

I tried with Opacity property of TButton. But, the property is making even Image as transparent.

Comment: So basically you use Image as a way to make nicer looking Button. Right? If that is so why don't you use the `Image.OnClick` event to handle clicks as you would do for buttons. This way you wont need buttons at all. Or even better why don't you use `OnMouseDown` and `OnMouseUp` events which also provide you with the location where you clicked. This can be used to check the color of the pixel and only execute certain code when pixel color matches certain criteria. This gives you ability to simulate custom shaped buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use only ImageView instead of Button and can perform action on image click..So you do not have to make button transparent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Trectangle, it's work good on Windows and Android, no use a lot of resources.

You can apply a fill property to make it Transparent, you can also using a OnDraw method to copy a transparent bitmap to the canvas.